# Help to prove an implication for continuous positive functions.

Tags: analysis

please I need help to prove the following implication:
If we assume that $f$ and $g$ are two non-negative continuous functions such that
$f(t) f^{'}(t) \leq f(t) g(t)\, \forall t \in [0,T] $ then $f^{'}(t) \leq g (t) \forall (0,T)$ or $f =0$.

I'm not even sure if this is true or not!! if anyone has an idea or a solution
I'll be grateful if he can share it with me.

Best regards.

Comment: Is $f'$ supposed to be continuous ?

Comment: No, but, if this hypothesis can solve the problem. It's ok, we can assume that f is of classes $C^1$ which means $f^{'}$ is continuous.

Comment: Yes, the problem is easier with this assumption. I am going to add an answer.

Comment: Please, share this answer with me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: (Notice that the "or $f=0$" is useless in the statement, since $f=0$ implies the fact that $f′\leq g$, because $g \geq 0$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's fix a $t$, and let's prove that $f'(t) \leq g(t)$.

If $f(t) \neq 0$, then dividing by $f(t)$ in the inequality $f(t)f'(t) \leq f(t) g(t)$ leads directly, because $f(t) > 0$, to $f'(t) \leq g(t)$ and you are done.

If $f(t)=0$, then $t$ is a minimum of $f$ because $f$ is supposed to be non-negative, so $f'(t)=0$, and you get $f'(t) \leq g(t)$ because $g(t) \geq 0$.

In both cases, you get $f'(t) \leq g(t)$, so you are done.

Comment: Thank you so much TheSilverDoe. you just save my day.

Comment: @walidfssm I edited.

Answer (score -2):

There is no need to involve any functions here. If $a >= 0$ and $a \cdot x ≤ a \cdot y$, then either $a = 0$ or $x ≤ y$. Therefore $f'(x) ≤ g(x)$ for all x where $f(x) ≠ 0$ and $f'(x)$ is defined. The conditions that g is continuous and $g(x) ≥ 0$ are not needed.

Comment: Yes but obviously, the question is to see if $f'\leq g$ or $f=0$ everywhere, and not pointwise.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe What? (f' ≤ g or f = 0) everywhere.

Comment: No, the question is "($f' \leq g$ everywhere) or ($f=0$ everywhere)" which is not the same thing. (and please don't be rude).

Comment: @TheSilverDoe  please if you don't mind I have another question: if we assume that $f \in C^{1}$ but $g$  is only integrable, is the above problem have a solution?

Comment: @walidfssm Yes, actually I just found a easier answer that works even if $f$ is not $\mathcal{C}^1$. I edit my answer.